# Missing XmlSchemaSet UWP

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, uwp

I'm trying to validate a xmldocument against a Xsd schema in UWP targeting Windows 10, but I'm unable to find XmlSchemaSet class and all the related methods.

System.Xml.Schema namespace seems to be incomplete.

Referenced assembly is System.Xml.ReaderWriter, Version=4.0.10.0

Is there any package to import?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

XmlSchema is not supported in UWP. [This document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt185484.aspx) describes the subset of System.Xml classes available in UWP.